# Does Appium 1.6 works with Xcode 8.2?

Tags: appium-ios, xcode8.2

I am using Appium 1.6.2 with Xcode 8.1 in my mac machine(Working on Mobile Automation). I need to update Xcode from 8.1 to 8.2. I am worried that I will run into issues if Appium 1.6 doesn't work with Xcode 8.2. Any one came across this situation or any idea on how it works? Please help.

Comment: Sai, try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi177Si5aLU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated to Appium 1.6.3 and Xcode 8.2 and the application launches correctly.

I have had to add a new Capability for using XCUITest

```
 automationName: 'XCUITest'
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. I am already using XCUITest capability with 8.1. Have you run scripts written for 8.1 or less with 8.2? Are there any issues with it? If its ok then I will update in my machine too.